# Is realm.write asynchronous

Tags: swift, asynchronous, realm

I am trying to add CustomUserData to my MongoDB Realm Database and then refresh the user data.

But as it seems is realm.write asynchronous, whereas I thought it would be synchronous ([Swift Realm Write method is Sync or Async Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630594/swift-realm-write-method-is-sync-or-async-thread)). So my question is what's really the case and when its synchronous why does the .refreshCustomData() function is only able to fetch the new data after a short delay.

```
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(member)
}

app.currentUser!.refreshCustomData()
// -> after the refresh the customUserData is still empty
// only if you call it with a short delay the result contains the new written data
```

Comment: Users need to use Realm Notifications.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code, I am not seeing the same behavior and we don't know what this `app.currentUser!.refreshCustomData()` does because the code was not included - that could be the cause of the issue.  `try! realm.write` just calls `beginWrite` and adds a *throws* for error handling. Please update your question to include the other code so we get an idea of what's going on. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not asynchronous.
Have a look at the implementation (removed everything that is not important to understand).
A write transaction is simply started and committed if no exception has occurred, otherwise the transaction is rolled back.

```
public func write<Result>(_ block: (() throws -> Result)) throws -> Result {
    beginWrite()
    var ret: Result!
    do {
        ret = try block()
    } catch let error {
        if isInWriteTransaction { cancelWrite() }
        throw error
    }
    if isInWriteTransaction { try commitWrite(withoutNotifying: tokens) }
    return ret
}
```

But: If you query the data just written in another thread, that is another story.
New objects just wont be visible on another thread for some time.

My solutions to this is: stay on the same thread for write and read operations.

See also: [Saving data and query it in different threads with Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790273/saving-data-and-query-it-in-different-threads-with-realm)